Incorporate retest reliability into model (in R)
I'm conducting a study to evaluate the impact of an intervention on a test outcome. Each participant takes the test before and after the intervention. Also there's a control group involved.
Given that the test outcome is a proportion, I've opted to utilize a general linear mixed-effects model. Specifically, I'm incorporating a random effect to accommodate potential variability in baseline levels among subjects, allowing for a unique intercept for each subject:
full_model <- glmer(cbind(successes, failures) ~ group * timepoint + (1|Subject), data = data, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))

However, the test I'm using is widely used in psychology, yet its retest reliability is only moderate, around 0.5 according to literature. Upon examining the correlation within my control group between pre and post outcomes, it aligns well with this reliability estimate.
I wonder whether there's a method to integrate this crucial information into my model. I perceive it as another random effect, but one whose 'strength' seems quantifiable. Yet, I'm struggling to conceptualize how to incorporate this effectively.

It seems to me that it is already incorporated. It is one form of noise, or measurement error. This is similar to any measurement that is not highly reliable, either on cross-sectional analysis or in repeated measures.
I don't know of any specific way to add it to a model as a separate term.
(You can and should add this to power analysis, but that's a separate topic).

I agree that this is probably the best approach if you are sticking with regression-style models. To go beyond this, you'd probably have to move over to a generalized sem type model where you model the outcome as a latent measurement variable. Then you could regress the predictors on the latent variable.

@ErikRuzek OK, but I think the OP wanted to model the reliability itself. I'm not sure you can do that, even in an SEM. Nor am I sure it's advisable, if it's possible.
